# <__main__.Node object at 0x0000028264343CA0> in Python

Tags: python, list

as I am trying to do my python programming, I didn't know how to solve the situation in this case

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.neighbours = []

a = Node('a')
b = Node('b')
c = Node('c')
d = Node('d')
e = Node('e')

a.neighbours = [d]
b.neighbours = [d, e]
c.neighbours = [e]
d.neighbours = [e]
e.neighbours = [a]

node_rela = {}
node_rela[a.name] = a.neighbours

print(node_rela)
```

The a.name is successfully shown as 'a', but I don't know why it can't apply to a.neighbours

`{'a': [<__main__.Node object at 0x000002424BF53CD0>]}`

How to solve the problem in this situation

Thanks a lot

Comment: "I didn't know how to solve the situation in this case" What "situation"? What happens when you run the code? What do you want to happen instead? Why? Why do you think the actual behaviour is a problem? Please read [ask] and *ask a question*.

Answer (score 2):

With

```
print(node_rela)
```

you're printing a dictionary.

With

```
print(a.name)
```

you're printing a string (`"a"`).

With

```
print(a)
```

you're printing an object.

With

```
print(a.neighbours)
```

you're printing a list.

If you want the Node objects to print differently than their default, learn about [`__str__` and `__repr__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/what-is-the-difference-between-str-and-repr).

It could look like this, for example:

```
def __repr__(self):
    neighbours = ", ".join(f"'{n.name}'" for n in self.neighbours)
    return f"Node('{self.name}' with neighbours {neighbours})"
```

Comment: what should I return in __repr__? when i do return self.neighbour it appears TypeError: __repr__ returned non-string (type list)

Comment: @EmptyMind: the error message says all: you returned a list but you're supposed to return a string.